# Swing «artifacts» on Linux for a very simple GUI program

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I'am learning on Java and Swing through a book (Filthy Rich Clients, not to cite it), and I tried the following short example code on Linux, (Oracle JDK 8):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class OvalComponent extends JComponent {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {    
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Oval");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.add(new OvalComponent());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Runnable doCreateAndShowGUI = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            } 
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doCreateAndShowGUI);
     }
}
```

When I run this code I strangely observe the following «artifact» on the `JFrame` border:

[image: artifact observed on JFrame]

This «artifact» remains when the window is dragged, but disappears when it is resized. I would like to understand why I have this strange behavior  on Linux. Is this inherent to Linux (on Windows 7 I observed no artifact), and what should/could be done in order to fix this «bug»?

I also observed that simply calling `super.paintComponent(Graphics g);` just at the beginning of `paintComponent` method solves the problem. But, very curiously, the authors in the book are saying that, in this particular case, a call to `super.paintComponent()` is not necessary.

My main question is: why do I observe this black artifact on my Java window?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the behavior on my system. Most likely the window-manager of your system resizes the window / reports a wrong size of the window on the first run, which `super.paintComponent(...)` amends by rechecking the size. Usually a bar like in your picture appears when the window is resized without being repainted immediately.

Comment: `Is this inherent to Linux` - I would suggest yes. Seems like a painting timing issue. A couple of suggestions: 1) Maybe try setting the size AFTER you add the oval component to the frame. This is the normal order for logic because normally you would invoke pack() to get the size of the frame after adding all the component. 2) maybe add a f.repaint() after the frame is visible.

Answer (score 2):

Same as Paul, I did not notice the artifact down the right-hand side as seen in the screen shot above. Having said that, it is likely caused by failure to call the super method. Calling it will cause the ***background*** of the component to be painted.

Here are some other advice I'd recommend implementing in the code, with code comments before each one to discuss why.

```
// A JPanel does some things automatically, so I prefer to use one
//public class OvalComponent extends JComponent {
public class OvalComponent extends JPanel {

    // Use @Override notation! 
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // call the super method first..
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // this is better achieved with the call to super
        //g.setColor(getBackground());
        //g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    // suggest a size for the layout manager(s) to use..
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Oval");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // DON'T TRY TO GUESS WHAT SIZE THE FRAME SHOULD BE!
        // f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.add(new OvalComponent());
        // Instead pack the top level container after components added
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Runnable doCreateAndShowGUI = () -> {
            createAndShowGUI();
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doCreateAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

Comment: (1+) for the suggestion to use a JPanel because it has a basic UI to paint the background of the component for you. This means you should have a consistent background as you move from one platform to another. However, you no longer need the `fillRect(...)` code to paint the background.

Comment: Thank's for each suggestion. Unfortunately, my precise question was about the necessity for (e.g.) adding a call to super.paintComponent(g), because, as I said, in the book that I'm reading, it is clearly said that, in this case, a call to super.Component(g) should not be necessary. Stated differently, which (probably) technical explanation could be given to understand that my java program, run under linux, doesn't exhibit the «normal» (and expected) behavior? I know my question may seem relatively marginal, but I'm quite puzzled:shouldn't Java  behave independently of the underlying platform?